# How to form adjacency matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, character, character-arrays

I am working on this code to find the adjacency matrix from the following matrix, mapr:

```
   'mad'     []       []      []

   'sister'  []       []      []

   'dog'     'inter'  'mad'   'said'
```

For the above matrix, based on the code I have written, this is the output I get which is not the desired one:

```
       0   1   1
       1   0   1
       1   1   0
```

The following is my code:

```
for i=1:no_of_rows
   for j=1:no_of_cols
      for m=i+1:no_of_rows
          for k=1:no_of_cols
             if(~isempty(mapr(i,j)))
               if(strcmp(mapr(i,j),mapr(m,k))==0)
                   Adjmatr(i,m)=1;
                   Adjmatr(m,i)=1;
                end
              end
          end
      end
    end
end
```

Can somebody help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show what you would expect the output to be, and why.

Comment: I want to compare the strings in each cell array and if they are the same, 1 is to be added in the corresponding adjacency matrix or else zero. Once I calculate the adjacency matrix I could calculate the eigen vector of the adjacency matrix. So according to my matrix mapr, Adjmat(1,2) and Adjmat(2,1) should be zero which is wrong.

Comment: So - what is the correct matrix?

Comment: The correct matrix should be:

       0 0 1
       0 0 0
       1 0 0

Comment: Presumably you meant for that to be a 3x3 square matrix. Can you explain why this is the result you expect? What defines "adjacency" in your system? Why are there only three nodes?

Comment: The three rows correspond to the three sentences I am reading from a text file with each cell containing each word from the sentences.According to the system I am designing, adjacency value should be 1 if any two sentences has common words.It can be seen that sentences 1 and 3 have the common word "sad" so only Adjmat(1,3) and (Adjmat(3,1) should be 1. But here according to the code that I have written empty cells are also taken into consideration which I think is the problem.Can you tell me how to omit the empty cell comparisons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is what you were looking for:

```
mapr={   'mad',      [],    [],     [];
      'sister',      [],    [],     [];
         'dog', 'inter', 'mad', 'said'};

s1 = size(mapr,1);
s2 = size(mapr,2);
result = zeros(s1, s1);
for i = 1 : s1
  for j = 1 : s2 - 1
    if ~isempty(mapr{i,j})
        for k = i+1:s1
            for l = j+1:s2
                 if strcmp(mapr{i,j}, mapr{k,l})
                    result(i,k) = 1;
                    result(k,i) = 1;
                 end
            end
        end
     end
  end
end
```

The resulting matrix is

```
0 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 0
```

I think the key was to move the `~isempty` out by one more loop, and not to test elements against themselves (adjacency matrix diagonal is zero)...

Comment: Happy to help. I hope you learnt from the back and forth that was needed before I could answer that you need to be quite precise in formulating your question. We all learn over time how to make this site work for us...

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little more compact. It uses [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate all combinations of rows, and [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to test adjancency between rows. `[]` (empty matrix) needs to be converted to `''` (empty string) so that `ismember` can be applied. Empty strings are explicitly taken care of so that they don't count for adjacency.

```
mapr = {'mad'    []       []      []
       'sister'  []       []      []
       'dog'     'inter'  'mad'   'said'}; %// example data

N = size(mapr,1);
mapr = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x), mapr, 'uni', 0); %// convert [] to ''
[ii,jj] = ndgrid(1:N); %// generate all combinations of rows
adjMatr = NaN(N,N); %// pre-shape result matrix
adjMatr(:) = arrayfun( @(n) ...
  any(ismember(mapr(ii(n),:), mapr(jj(n),:)) & ... %// check adjancency
  ~cellfun('isempty', mapr(ii(n),:))), 1:numel(ii) ); %// rule out empty strings 
adjMatr = adjMatr - eye(N); %// remove self-coincidences
```